# How do I query security groups for EC2 instances?

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to compile a full list of EC2 instances in my AWS account via the aws-cli. I'm successfully querying everything except the associated security groups for each instance. When I try pulling the security group name it comes through as None. Below is the command I've run. I've also tried 'Groups'.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],InstanceId,Placement.AvailabilityZone,State.Name,KeyName,SecurityGroups.GroupName]' --output table
```

Comment: Feel fee to edit your question to show the desired output. Getting nicely formatted output might be difficult from the command-line. Are you comfortable using a language like Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because each instance might have multiple security groups assigned to it, so `SecurityGroups` is an array. you can access the first element in the array if instead of doing:

```
SecurityGroups.GroupName
```

you'll do:

```
SecurityGroups[0].GroupName
```

but that will show you only the first security group in the list. If you want to see the whole list you'll have to change your query to something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region "us-west-2" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups[].GroupName |[*]]' --output text
```

Comment: This is helpful! I thought it might have something to do with if there was multiple security groups. The above solution still only provides one security group however. Any tips on listing all security groups for each instance?

Comment: that still produces one security group at a time. I ran the command 

aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0],InstanceId,Placement.AvailabilityZone,State.Name,KeyName,SecurityGroups[].GroupName |[0]]' --output table

Comment: You can't have `--output table` since you're getting multiple elements for the same row, you'll have to use `--output text` instead, try: `aws ec2 describe-instances --region "us-west-2"  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups[].GroupName |[*]]' --output text`

Comment: Getting so close, thank you again. Problem with this is now the security groups are on their own line which makes it hard to format this into some kind of readable table. For example:
line 1: Name, InstanceId, Zone, State, Key Name
line 2: Security group 1, SG 2, SG 3
line 3: Name, InstanceId, Zone, State, Key Name
and so on

Comment: you'll have to work around it, one way to do it: you can output it into a text file and then: `sed 'N;s/\n/ /' aws_output.txt`.Another way is to create a small script that parses the output. But there's no way around the fact that multiple SG could be attached to the same instance and there's no way to know how many of them will be showing up when you're running the CLI command.

Comment: Got it! Used the sed command but used tab as a new line delimiter. Thanks for your help man.